# MySQL JOIN query more tables and return more result in one select

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I would question, sorry my bad english :(

I have multiple tables

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_slovak_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_slovak_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_slovak_ci;


CREATE TABLE `user_acl` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `group` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_slovak_ci;


CREATE TABLE `user_profil` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_slovak_ci NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_slovak_ci NOT NULL,
  `profil` text COLLATE utf8_slovak_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_slovak_ci;
```

Query:

```
SELECT user.*, prf.*, acl.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 1) AS user
LEFT JOIN user_acl AS acl ON (acl.id_user = user.id)
INNER JOIN user_profil AS prf ON (user.id = prf.id)
```

I have table `user`, `user_acl`, `user_profil`

table `user` and `user_profil` are indexed under `id` what is the common key

Table `user_acl` have `id_user`common key with table `user` (id) in the table but `user_acl` There are more rows for the table `user` and I need all rows from a table `user_acl` in one query.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, because I tested this, and it seemed to work.

Comment: I need to query returned only one row now more depending on there are rows in `user_acl`

Comment: Do you mean that you want all the `acl` rows to show up in one row?

Comment: Now use in PHP foreach($db->Select($sql) as $value) {
            if(isset($users[$value['id']]['group'])) {
                $value['group'] = $users[$value['id']]['group'].','.$value['group'];
            }
            $users[$value['id']] = $value;
        }

Comment: "Do you mean that you want all the acl rows to show up in one row?" yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get MySQL to combine values from multiple rows into one row with `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT user.*, prf.*, GROUP_CONCAT(acl.id), GROUP_CONCAT(acl.group) 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN user_acl AS acl ON (acl.id_user = user.id) 
INNER JOIN user_profil AS prf ON (user.id = prf.id) 
GROUP BY user.id;
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much. This really helped me and I learned another important command. Once again, thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to separate query, if you need more than one acl row to one user row.
[EDIT]: But if you need to to it with one query then you should use somekindof bitwise operations. http://codingrecipes.com/how-to-write-a-permission-system-using-bits-and-bitwise-operations-in-php